# Perl XML::Parser - howto access a simple parsed tree?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I want to parse a simple string using XML::Parser. This works fine. But I do not know how to access the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Parser;

my $parser = XML::Parser->new( Style => 'Tree' );
my $tree   = $parser->parse( '<xml type="test" Id="ca19cfd5" result="1 test 2 test 3" elapsed="9" Size="12345" />' );

print Dumper( $tree );
```

shows me

```
$VAR1 = [
'xml',
[
{
'Size' => '12345',
'Id' => 'ca19cfd5',
'type' => 'test',
'elapsed' => '9',
'result' => '1 test 2 test 3'
 }
 ]
 ];
```

So it perfectly could parse my string. But how do I access these fields? Something like "my $result = $tree..."

The given xml string will always have the same syntax like shown above. Only the content differs.

Tnx in advance,
Enkidu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes you are looking for are in `$tree->[1]->[0]`

```
my $atts= $tree->[1]->[0];
```

then

```
print "size: $atts->{Size}\n";
```

That said XML::Parser is not the easiest module to use, it's a bit too low-level. XML::Twig or XML::LibXML will give you what you want more easily.

Comment: Great! Tnx!

Well, XML::Parser is the only available XML module on that server. And installing perl modules on a system not connected to Internet is a pain! :( ;)

Comment: Btw, how can I get a list of all existing attributes?

Comment: the list of attributes: `keys %$atts`

Answer (score 1):

You may look to other XML Parsers, that produce simplier structures

For example my modules:

- XML::Fast
- XML::Hash::LX
- XML::Parser::Style::ETree